# Determine lambda parameter of exponential distribution from covariance

Tags: probability, covariance, exponential-distribution

Good morning,

Given an exponential distribution such that $X$ ~ $Exp(\lambda)$

with $Sn = \sum_{i=1}^n Xi$.

Given that $Cov(S_{31}, S_{57}) = 31 + 57$, find the lambda parameter of the exponential distribution.

I honestly do not know how to go about this. I know that the formula for Cov is :
$Cov(X,Y) = E(XY) - E(X)E(Y)$ but this doesn't help me very much. I cannot determine $E(S_{31}S_{57})$ in my case.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ are exponentially distributed *independent* random variables with the parameter $\lambda$. If $n>m$, then
$$
\operatorname{Cov}(S_m,S_n)=\operatorname{Cov}\biggl(\sum_{i=1}^mX_i,\sum_{i=1}^mX_i\biggr)+\operatorname{Cov}\biggl(\sum_{i=1}^mX_i,\sum_{i=m+1}^nX_i\biggr)=\operatorname{Var}S_m
$$
and
$$
\operatorname{Var}S_m=\sum_{i=1}^m\operatorname{Var}X_i=m\operatorname{Var}X_1
$$
using the independence and identical distributions. Since $\operatorname{Var}X_1=\lambda^{-2}$,
$$
\operatorname{Cov}(S_m,S_n)=\frac m{\lambda^2}.
$$
In this particular example $m=31$ and $\operatorname{Cov}(S_{31},S_{57})=31+57$. Hence,
$$
\lambda=\sqrt{\frac{31}{88}}.
$$

Comment: That looks good to me, took me a while to understand the first equation though. Another question if you don't mind. Let's assume that Z is a random variable that corresponds to the number of N trials where Sn < 4.5. What kind of law does Z follow ? I thought about the geometric law, but it doesn't sound right since the probability of success is obviously not static (it increases as N increases).

Comment: More like $Z = n$ where $Sn < 4.5$

Comment: I will explain the problem in the literal sense. The random variable X (described above) corresponds to the electricity consumption in a given day. Sn is the cumulative consumption (so the sum of the first n X). 

Let Z be the number of days where the cumulative consumption is lower than 4.5. What distribution law does Z follow ?

Comment: @WassimH It should be the Poisson distribution.